# UIPopoverController without interface builder?

Tags: interface-builder, uipopovercontroller

Are there any tutorials on UIPopoverController or creating UIPopovers without using interface builder?

I want to learn what is happening first before I use IB. All of the tutorials I have seen have been with interface builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned very fast with the sample code "Popover" at the Xcode library. It shows with very simple coding how set up a popover and present it.

Comment: Where is the XCode Library?

Comment: If you open xcode, on the first mask select "Learn about using Xcode" and type in the search field popover after entering the libary area. On the lower end of the main menue you will see a segment with a list of sample projects. Select popover project and you can see the project on the editor.